# jQuery Smooth Scroll to Top AND to Anchor by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

I'm finding answers for adding jQuery scroll to top OR scroll to anchors, but not really both integrated. So hope it's OK to ask here.

We have current jQuery function to add a scroll-to-top anchor for longer pages. It works fine.

```
// Add To Top Button functionality
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    // Scroll (in pixels) after which the "To Top" link is shown
    var offset = 700,
    //Scroll (in pixels) after which the "back to top" link opacity is reduced
    offset_opacity = 1200,
    //Duration of the top scrolling animation (in ms)
    scroll_top_duration = 700,
    //Get the "To Top" link
    $back_to_top = $('.to-top');

//Visible or not "To Top" link
    $(window).scroll(function(){
    ( $(this).scrollTop() > offset ) ? $back_to_top.addClass('top-is-visible') : $back_to_top.removeClass('top-is-visible top-fade-out');
    if( $(this).scrollTop() > offset_opacity ) { 
        $back_to_top.addClass('top-fade-out');
    }
});

//Smoothy scroll to top
$back_to_top.on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: 0 ,
        }, scroll_top_duration
    );
});

});
```

- How would this be modified to also allow smooth scrolling to anchors on page, using an ID (e.g, `<h2 id="anchor-name">`), without conflicts?

TO CLARIFY: We need either a modification to the above script, or a complete new one that will not conflict with it, that will add smooth scrolling to any anchor link found in the existing HTML of a page (e.g., `<a href="#any-anchor-link">`). The JS should detect any anchor links and add the smooth scrolling functionality to it. We would not manually add specific anchor links to the JS.

Comment: How would you want to identify the ID to scroll to? Parse the url on page load? Or some other type of input (mouse click on href)?

Comment: yes there isn't enough information in your question to determine _what_ to scroll to. in fact that is probably the hard part, scrolling to it is trivial with jquery

Comment: why not use real anchor links and let jquery handle those, so the fall back is normal behaviour? :)

Comment: If you want to parse the url and find the anchor to scroll to, then you could locate that element's Y offset on scroll to it in the .ready().

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity here. The anchors and the links to the anchors would be manually added to the HTML (using WordPress, so added to the page). I just wanted ANY links on a page that direct you to an ID to smoothly scroll instead of hard jump, while not messing up current 'Scroll to Top' functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracted the scrolling logic into its own function, which accepts an element's `id` as an argument.

```
//Smoothy scroll to top
$back_to_top.on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    targetedScroll();
});

// example of smooth scroll to h2#anchor-name
$('#some-button').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    targetedScroll('anchor-name');
});

// bind smooth scroll to any anchor on the page
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    targetedScroll($(this).attr('href').substr(1));
});

// scrolling function
function targetedScroll(id) {
    // scrollTop is either the top offset of the element whose id is passed, or 0
    var scrollTop = id ? $('#' + id).offset().top : 0;

    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: scrollTop,
    }, scroll_top_duration);
}
```

Comment: Tried replacing everything from `//Smoothy scroll to top` down in my code with this, but no luck. Scroll to top still works, but anchor links not smooth. Does this require specific anchors be added to JS, or will it be picked up from HTML on page?!? Sorry, not very JS fluent. I tried adding a current anchor ID to replace your 'anchor-name' as test, but this did not work either. Need it to just pick up existing anchor links (e.g., `<a href="#any-anchor-name>`) in HTML when on any page.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I posted an edit which should do exactly what you described. Every anchor tag with an HREF starting with `#` will scroll to an element with the corresponding ID.