# jQuery Smooth Scroll to Top AND to Anchor by ID (with Offset)

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

this is an extension to a questions that was previously answered here: [See Prevoius Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37931726/jquery-smooth-scroll-to-top-and-to-anchor-by-id)

I have a bit of jQuery that is adding BOTH a smooth scroll to top function, AND a smooth scroll to any anchor found on a page.

Now, I just need to add an offset to the anchor scroll (110px) to account for fixed headers, WITHOUT messing up the scroll to top function.

Here's the existing code:

```
// Add To Top Button + Smooth Scroll to Anchors functionality
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // Scroll (in pixels) after which the "To Top" link is shown
    var offset = 700,
    //Scroll (in pixels) after which the "back to top" link opacity is reduced
    offset_opacity = 1200,
    //Duration of the top scrolling animation (in ms)
    scroll_top_duration = 700,
    //Get the "To Top" link
    $back_to_top = $('.to-top');

//Visible or not "To Top" link
$(window).scroll(function(){
    ( $(this).scrollTop() > offset ) ? $back_to_top.addClass('top-is-visible') : $back_to_top.removeClass('top-is-visible top-fade-out');
    if( $(this).scrollTop() > offset_opacity ) { 
        $back_to_top.addClass('top-fade-out');
    }
});

//Smooth scroll to top
$back_to_top.on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    targetedScroll();
});

// example of smooth scroll to h2#anchor-name
$('#some-button').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    targetedScroll('anchor-name');
});

// bind smooth scroll to any anchor on the page
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    targetedScroll($(this).attr('href').substr(1));
});

// scrolling function
function targetedScroll(id) {
    // scrollTop is either the top offset of the element whose id is passed, or 0
    var scrollTop = id ? $('#' + id).offset().top : 0;

    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: scrollTop,
    }, scroll_top_duration);
}

});
```

Comment: On my site, I just gave an anchor to first element on the page beneath the navbar. That way you can still use the offset.

Comment: Hi, not sure I follow you here about adding an additional anchor or 'still using the offset' (I haven't set an offset yet, that's what I was hoping to find out how to add).

Answer (score 0):

Any time your're scrolling to an element, you have to scroll lower than the element by the height of the fixed navbar. Similarly, the first element on the page needs a margin or padding to offset by the height of the navbar.

Since both of these offsets are the same, you can set the offset for scrolling at the same time you set the offset for the first element. When you're scrolling to an element, subtract the offset from the height from the top. This will still work even when scrolling to the top.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var offset = $("nav").height();
    $("body").css("padding-top", offset + "px");
    $('a[href^="#"]').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var scrollY = $(this.href).offset().top;
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: scrollY - offset
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hmmm, not sure I understand how this is supposed to work. I added this function after the existing code (above), and it only seemed to add a manual padding to the body tag. So the header and everything are all pushed down. But even with this, the anchor links still direct to the very top of the page (above the padding). So it's almost like I need the opposite of this (padding on the anchors, not the body). And just an FYI, I can't do most of the CSS-only workarounds as the anchors are visible elements (h2) and already have pseudo elements in use (h2:before).

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle that shows the problem? BTW, here's my site where I got it to work (with modifications too): http://ignite.bentonvillek12.org/

Comment: Hi, it's coming from a WordPress site, so would take quite a while to dummy something up with enough dependencies and styles to be a good example. It looks like part of your code is to determine and add top padding to body. This alone doesn't help mine, and when I disabled on yours the anchors still worked. So guessing it's in the last lines? Do those conflict with what my code is already doing, or could they be integrated together?